# Failed GET Request ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

For some reason when I set a breakpoint for a controller constructor and a method in an ASP.NET Core project, I am unable to hit either breakpoint but get a weird little "4 requests" thing over my method. Probably something urped up by Resharper or something half-baked into the framework. Not sure.

[image]

So somehow it is figuring out the caller wants to hit this endpoint, but it returns a 404 anyway and doesn't say why. Doesn't that mean it can't find the endpoint? But if it doesn't find it why is it upticking the requests thing?

I disabled all routes that could be interfering with this and there are no filters in this assembly.

I also tried adding the [AllowAnonymous] annotation. No success!

[image]

I have first chance exceptions enabled, but nothing ever shows up.

?!?!!?!!

This seems super simple. The margin for error seems razor thin. What is going on here? My diagnostic capabilities are compromised by all the energy all the energy I am putting into invectives against MS and JetBrains.

Comment: Does this affects only one your project/solution, or any project (including new-empty one)?

Comment: @Dmitry: seems to be for all projects. I don't know how to positively identify what type of project I inherited, but I created an MVC WebAPI project with a controller class and got the same opaque red X with "1 request" by it :(

Comment: @micahhoover Could you replicate the issue in new project? If so, could you post it to GitHub?

Comment: Could be CORS issue. check if the CORS enabled for calling website

Comment: I got similar issues but there was problem with my code that needed fixed. I think you need to post more code it will be something you have made since your last successful run